# Angular & NGRX: Filtering on a selector using NGRX entity

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, ngrx, ngrx-entity

I am trying to filter out the payload data by a property.

```
 //reducer.ts

  case MessagesActionTypes.LOAD_Message_SUCCESS: {
      console.log('reducer='+ 
      JSON.stringify(action.payload.Messages));//receiving data here
      return adapter.addAll(action.payload.Messages, state);
    }

    export const getSelectedMessageId = (state: MessageState) => state.selectedMessageId;

// get the selectors
const { selectIds, selectEntities, selectAll, selectTotal } = adapter.getSelectors();


// select the array of Messages
export const selectAllMessages = selectAll;
```

Below is the selector

```
 //     Selector.ts

export const selectHomeQueues = createSelector(
  fromReducer.selectAllMessages,
 (messages) => messages.filter(message => message.queue === 'HOME')
 );
```

I am **receiving data** in the reducer but **getting error** in the selector during runtime `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Note: I havent been able to find any example on filtering in NGRX entity selectors anywhere.

How do we filter the selectors in NGRX entity?

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same issue. You need to change your selector very slightly to:

```
export const selectHomeQueues = createSelector(
  selectAllMessages,
 (messages) => messages.filter(message => message.queue === 'HOME')
 );
```

Where `selectAllMessages` is  a selector that you have defined simply as:

```
export const selectAllMessages = createSelector(
  fromReducer.selectAllMessages
 );
```

The way we were trying to do this originally was via the adapter and i suspect we have made a small blunder or misconception somewhere along the way.

This issue came about as the result of an angular or redux version upgrade. Not sure about the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like that:

```
const getSelectHomeQueues = (store) => {
    return store.select(fromReducer.selectAllMessages)
        .filter(message => message.queue === 'HOME')
}
```

Wherever you want to use it:

```
getSelectHomeQueues(this.store).subscribe(...)
```

Comment: I want to have a dedicated filter selector in the selectors file.
is `const getSelectHomeQueues` being defined in the selector or the component?

Comment: Among the selectors.

Comment: I might be missing something. How do we Import store into the selectors when it doesnt even have a constructor?

Comment: Lets play with an example. You have a component and you inject store in the constructor. Also you want to use getSelectHomeQueues in this component so you just insert the second code snippet. You do not have to import store to the selectors. By calling getSelectHomeQueues you pass the reference of store.

Comment: getting an error ` TypeError: store.select(...).filter is not a function` on the selector return statement

Comment: If you are using rxjs 6 or higher, then you have to pipe it.

Comment: I am trying to make this work. Removed the filter and ran it. Its now giving me 
`core.js:1542 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined   at entity.js:27  at store.js:528`

Comment: Could you please create a stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

The error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" suggests you are getting an error elsewhere because in the code you provided in your question we don't see `map` anywhere.

In your selector you are filtering on `messages` and it passes `header` which is never used. It *appears* you are not filtering individual messages, but message queues, so:

```
export const selectHomeQueues = createSelector(
  fromReducer.selectAllMessages,
 (messages) => messages.queue === 'HOME'
 );
```