# How do I test NgRx factory selectors using "selectEntities" or "selectAll" from @ngrx/entity with Jasmine?

Tags: jasmine, ngrx-entity

#### Description

Following the description in the docs [@ngrx/entity](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/adapter), I wrote a factory selector that uses `selectAll` and `selectEntities` provided by `EntityAdapter`:

```js
export const selectEntityWithBuiltinSelectors = (userInput: string) =>
  createSelector(selectMyFeatureState, (state): MyEntity | undefined => {
    const id = Number(userInput);
    const nameToLowerCase = userInput.toLowerCase();
    return isNaN(id)
      ? selectAll(state).find(
          (entity) => entity.name.toLowerCase() === nameToLowerCase,
        )
      : selectEntities(state)[id];
  });
```

In the running application this works as expected.

However, writing a unit test

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  mockEntity = { id: 5, name: 'foo' };
  featureState = {
    entities: { [mockEntity.id]: mockEntity },
    ids: [mockEntity.id],
    isLoading: false,
    searchResult: null,
    errorMessage: '',
  };
});
it('should at least reach the expect case', () => {
  const result = selectEntityWithBuiltinSelectors(
    mockEntity.name,
  ).projector(featureState);
  expect(result).toBe(result);
});
```

fails at the point where I use `projector` with the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ids')
```

It doesn't even reach the expect case.

Going through the debugger in WebStorm shows, that the argument `state` from the factory selector is actually set to the feature State Object and does have a property `ids` - although its array is empty. Still, that doesn't fit with the error message, that it cannot read a property of `undefined`.

#### Example code

I have reproduced the scenario [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-c3uznj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-feature%2F%2Bstore%2Fmy-entity.selectors.spec.ts) on stackblitz.

#### What i have tried

If I don't use the `selectAll` and `selectEntities` functions, but just the state object getters, the test succeeds:

```js
export const selectEntityWithWorkaround = (userInput: string) =>
  createSelector(selectMyFeatureState, (state): MyEntity | undefined => {
    const id = Number(userInput);
    const nameToLowerCase = userInput.toLowerCase();
    return isNaN(id)
      ? Object.values(state.entities).find(
          (entity: MyEntity | undefined) =>
            entity?.name.toLowerCase() === nameToLowerCase,
        )
      : state.entities[id];
  });
```

Although this is a workaround for the problem, it would render the adapter's selectors useless.

Unfortunately I couldn't find an example in the docs or on google that shows a test of a factory selector using `selectAll` and `selectEntities` of @ngrx/entity.

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52953910/angular-ngrx-filtering-on-a-selector-using-ngrx-entity) question might be related, but I can't see that its answers are helping in my case.

#### Summary

1. How do I mock my state so that I can test this kind of selector?
2. Do I need to use `provideMockStore()` - and if so, how and why (since selectors should be pure functions)?
3. Can I use `projector` at all in this scenario or is there another way to test a selector?